# Identity server 4 reference token with MVC

Tags: access-token, identityserver4

I am using Identity server 4(with entity-framework for configs) and defining a MVC client with reference token (AccessTokenType=1). I can login to IS4 by using the client and defined user and get access token (reference type). I know that this token does not contains claims but I have all claims in Security.Claims.ClaimPrincipal. Is it getting claims by doing behind the scene request to IS4?

I have 2 main issues:

1) I set the access token life time to 10 mins for MVC client, and cookie is valid for 450 hours. I expect that after 10 mins user redirected to login page on IS4 as access token is expired but it is not happening

2) Also when I remove PersistedGrants from database, still I am logged in and can see MVC client, Why?
Should I do anything in middleware on MVC client to check access token by using reference token?
I need this for forcing user to login on all logged in clients again.
this my MVC setting:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(
    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(750),
        AutomaticChallenge = true
    });

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
        SignInScheme = "Cookies",
        Authority = "http://localhost:7010",
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        ClientId = "MVC_Client",
        ClientSecret = "MVC_Client",
        ResponseType = "code id_token",
        Scope =
        {
            Common.Constants.IdentityManagement.OpenIdScopeName,
            Common.Constants.IdentityManagement.ProfileScopeName,
            Common.Constants.IdentityManagement.EmailScopeName,
        },
        GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
        SaveTokens = true,
        TokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
            },
        Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
        {
            OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceived
        }
    });
```

The client has two grant types: hybrid,client_credentials

And this is client properties in databse:

```
[AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime]: 60
[AccessTokenLifetime]: 60
[AccessTokenType]: 1
[AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser]: False 
[AllowOfflineAccess]: True
[AllowPlainTextPkce]: False
[AllowRememberConsent]: True
[AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken]: False
[AlwaysSendClientClaims]: False
[AuthorizationCodeLifetime]: 60
[ClientId]: MVC_Client
[ClientName]: MVC_Client
[ClientUri]: NULL
[EnableLocalLogin]: True
[Enabled]: True
[IdentityTokenLifetime]: 60
[IncludeJwtId]: False
[LogoUri]: NULL
[LogoutSessionRequired]: True
[LogoutUri]: NULL
[PrefixClientClaims]: True
[ProtocolType]: oidc
[RefreshTokenExpiration]:  60
[RefreshTokenUsage]: 1
[RequireClientSecret]: True
[RequireConsent]: False
[RequirePkce]: False
[SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime]: 60
[UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the similar issue and I set the life time of the cookie according the life time of access token and after refreshing of access token it will be renew the cookie.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                ...

                SaveTokens = true,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {                   
                    OnTicketReceived = n => OnTicketReceived(n)
                }

            });

private Task OnTicketReceived(TicketReceivedContext n)
{
var accessTokenExpiresAt = n.Properties.Items[".Token.expires_at"];
n.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Parse(accessTokenExpiresAt);

return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Another way how you can manage the cookie is used the following method `OnValidatePrincipal`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = LastChangedValidator.ValidateAsync
    }
});

public static class LastChangedValidator
{
    public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
    {
        // Check if user is still valid 

        if (!isUserValid)
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();

            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jenan.

Set cookie expiry to token expiry works.

Another issue I have is that when I remove the reference tokens from PersistedGrants and after 10 mins (access token lifetime) the cookie is expired and I expect that user get redirected to login page. But MVC client goes to IS and IS creates new reference token without authentication. How it is possible?

In the IdentityServer log I see this:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:7010/connect/authorize?client_id=IdentityManagement&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7777%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20Roles%20IdentityManagement%20IdentityUsers&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636452284146749770.ZTk3YzFiM2QtYTQxMi00MGI3LWJjMGEtMWFkOGRhYTE0ZjE3NDhjZGE3MjMtYTczNS00Y2ZkLThhOTctNzAxYmM4NTY4MjE5&state=CfDJ8HzK9L_BsbZJtObgOKdlRawJPSBTZc1UETnT9osu2OIOojB6vxT7t7GjIBO2nf2TYngPk3u8EcDMk8o_dVUvj8VTaEQf0s1DvTUwaxZn93_TKv1waoFukeEBFwaSB1yWTbNq62dyYkLc6_fkiW4r16BwFyKpVEvaMmh2NGLUmfFiQ-7qj6f4VyR3pM0ydd7Ah8Vs6BIfXlyqtQJ4Ak4sR1jrcGO9-ViTWCFe2YN0M9-OWFluiFQOylh4quzwseYjjOgY0ruVCwK7Lw1pvVMewnn_f2uiXk7QXBz7TMYcp8kylbdgL5Vx0fSBrB67nKSER5m-gjPXNIky6FrBPSouqzw  
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware] HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: "idsrv".
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware] AuthenticationScheme: "idsrv" was successfully authenticated.
[IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint" for "/connect/authorize"
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware]     AuthenticationScheme: "idsrv" was successfully authenticated.
```

Why IdentityServer creates new reference token without authentication. The previous reference token is removed from PersistedGrants.

I am doing this for forcing user to login again in case of emergency (losing device,...)

Comment: You have two cookies - one cookie is in your MVC application and second cookie is in the IdentityServer (IS). If is expired your MVC cookie - the middleware automatically redirect the user to authentificate to the IS. If is cookie in IS still valid then you are redirect back to your MVC App with new token.

Comment: You are right. It is the case. How can I change the IS cookie to align with MVC cookie and token expiry? Is it a good practice to set all expiry the same?

Comment: I think this is special use case where you want to set up the IS cookie for same time as your client. I think the most common scenario is set the IS cookie for longer time because you want to use this cookie for single sign-on purpose and you don't want to re-login again and again. In this case I am wondering for IS setup extra cookie middleware and configure the OnValidate principal and check some flag on user - this user press some emergency button and it is necessary login again. Typically your IS is not only for one client and set the cookie of IS same as one client - I don't think so. :)

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/options.html and for extra cookie middleware - http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html

Comment: As I said I need this for  forcing user to login again. When I remove reference token for the user then if I have long live IS cookie, MVC client continues working without forcing user to login again. This is purpose of having reference token, right? to be able to invoke access whenever I want. So having a long live IS cookie breaks this.
Ideally when IS see reference token coming (from client cookie or IS cookie) which does not exist in PersistedGrants then user should be forced to login again. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are right - please take a look on method OnValidatePrincipal in Cookie middleware in this place you can create these things - like forcing user to re-login if. Sample of some configuration of cookie middleware - https://github.com/blowdart/IgniteDotNetConf/tree/master/CookieAuthFromScratch

Comment: Isn't it a client thing? Where the IS cookie is created? I guess it is created when user redirected to IS login and the IS cookie is created there. Am I right?

Comment: IS's cookie is created after login in the IS.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, I used this for set the IS cookie:

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(120)
                    };

await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(userCredential.User.Id.ToString(), userCredential.User.UserName, props);
```

But I do not want to set it the same as client cookie expiry as it affects SSO. Also if I set the IS cookie greater than client cookie the other issue happens (as IS cookie is valid IS creates new reference token without authentication).

Now I am confused!

Comment: I am confused too :) What do you want to do? You can implement OnValidatePrincipal method and in this method create some logic how will be cookie valid/reject it. In background you can say - this user must go login again and existing cookie in IS remove.

Comment: You mean on OnValidatePrincipal I can check the reference token exist and is valid?

Comment: Yes, it is part of it. I will create a demo for you and upload it on Github.

Comment: I tried the OnValidatePrincipal on my client but before firing this event the client call IS endpoint and IS issues a new reference token.

Comment: Yes you are right. You need create extra logic for IS for this "emergency" state. You can implement OnValidatePrincipal method in IS side and in this method create some logic - if this subid has in database flag need to login again - remove his cookie on IS.

Comment: Well I read that using reference token give flexibility of revoking token. Is it just for API and not MVC clients? cause It seems that even using reference token there is not easy way to revoke access for MVC clients.
It is working for my API but not for MVC client.

Comment: Yes, because access token is for API access - in MVC app is used the ID Token which tell to MVC this is user name Bob and has these roles. If you want to access from the MVC to some Api you use the access token for that. If you want to force login again after revoking the access token you must implement some extra logic how we mentioned above - some extra check in MVC and IS and modify cookie. :)

Comment: Well that is on IS endpoint which I do not have controls on and I could not find events on IS to do that. Could you please give an example how I can do that. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jenan, Any luck?

Comment: Hey - Yes, I've created some sample - but I am wondering how now manage if your access token expired - what do you expect? If your access token expired you want to redirect to IS or silently it refresh?

Comment: Well, in a regular scenario I just silently refresh the token. But in case of revoking access (removing reference token from IS database) I expect user get redirected to login page again for authentication.

Comment: I implemented on OnValidatePrincipal event so when the token is about to expire, the token get refreshed from IS silently. In this stage I check the validity of token on IS (check reference token) by using Introspection endpoint. But the issue is that when the token is expired (client cookie), the OnValidatePrincipal event is not getting fired and I am redirected to IS, now because the IS cookie is still valid, IS creates a new reference token and returns it to client. Even reference token is removed from DB for user, user can continue working and this what I don't want. (sorry it became long)

Comment: Please, take a look: https://github.com/Jenan/IdentityServer4.EmergencyLogout - If you want to revoke access token on http://localhost:5000/grants - try revoke all your sessions. That is my attempt for emergency revocation.

Comment: Thanks Jenan for the prototype. It is on Core 2.0 and I have an issue on AppCookieAuthenticationEvents.cs on IdentityServer project (I use Core 1.0). I cannot following:
`code`
            //Register new cookie middleware
            services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerConfig.CookieName)
                .AddCookie(IdentityServerConfig.CookieName, cookie =>
                {
                    cookie.EventsType = typeof(AppCookieAuthenticationEvents);
                });
`code`

Is it adding new middleware for IS cookie, right?

Comment: I meant new cookie middleware because it is required register new cookie middleware if you want to modify cookie mechanism. What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: oh sorry I am using .net framework 4.6.
I added following to Idebtityserver startup:
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(
                    new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                        Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents { OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync }
                    });

But it is not fired at all.

Comment: Try use this - services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authentication.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies";
                })
Consider to upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 :-)

Comment: Did not change anything. Also in your sample code when I click on "Logout all my sessions in IdentityServer". In client I can continue work without asking authentication again. So it does not force me login again!

Comment: You have to revoke access to api first and then force logout all session - it is not connected in sample code :)